# How do I use scandir (or another method) to sort the directory results alphabetically?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, readdir, scandir

Not skilled with PHP at all. I used old code from another site (that I did not write) to create a CMS for a client. Problem is, the directory results here are not returned alphabetically. I have read that scandir will do that, whereas readdir will not. I also know that an array or any number of sort functions would also work... I just don't know how to do it :) Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<select name="image1[<?print($i);?>]">
<option value="none.gif">no photo available</option>
<?
$handle = opendir($art_image);
while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
    if ($file !="." && $file !="..") {
        option($file,$row["image1"]);
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Have you checked the manual on `scandir`? Pretty much explains it all.

Comment: Nope. As I stated, "Not skilled with PHP at all". Hence, I don't write PHP or understand its syntax. This is why I am here.

Comment: @user1898972, has this been solved?

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="image1[<?print($i);?>]">
<option value="none.gif">no photo available</option>
<?

while ($item = scandir($art_image, SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING)) 
{
    if ('.' !== $item[0]) // skip . .. and hidden files all in one swoop
    {
        option($item, $row['image1']);
    }
}

?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($file = scandir($art_image)) {
...
```

That should do it for you. No handle required with scandir.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) and then sort the array() with [sort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Note that is customary to leave a example code when providing a answer, also, for future reference, try to provide a more complete answer, since many users flag/downvote short answers.